# Is there a way to listen to browser violation to trap it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture the browser console information. I am able to capture console logs, console errors , console warns and console info but violations are not being recorded through the below procedure.

Is there any way to trap console violations?

Below is the code I have tried to capture warns and info

```
var oldWarn = console.warn;
console.warn = function (message) {
    log.push({'type': 1, 'msg' : message, 'args':new Error(arguments).stack.split('\n')[1]});
    oldWarn.apply(console, arguments);
};

var oldInfo = console.info;
console.info = function (message) {
    log.push({'type': 2, 'msg' : message, 'args':new Error(arguments).stack.split('\n')[1]});
    oldWarn.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Comment: What kind of violations are you referring to? No, cannot capture all information that's displayed in error messages in the devtools, which are running with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to error logs, logs generated using the console.error, then you could do exactly what you did with console.warn and console.info.

However if you are referring to exceptions, then you need to add an event listener for error events on the window like this, which is a [global event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

```
window.addEventListener('error', (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
   // do what you want with the error here
   // When the function returns true, this prevents the firing of the default event handler.
});
```

Notice that while global error listener is well supported in all major browsers, and since quite a long time. the structure of parameters that are sent to the event listener is different between browsers (but i could not find that info in the mdn link that i shared)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not looking up this. I am inclined to capture such violations. eg: [Violation] 'load' handler took 160ms